# Assign variable in if condition

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I am trying to use a **text variable value** in an **if condition** parathesis.

Using PHP

```
<?php
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    $condition = '$a < $b';
    if($condition)
    { echo "Condition is TRUE"; } else
    { echo "Condition is FALSE"; }
?>
```

Expected Answer:

Condition is TRUE

Comment: I guess `$condition = $a < $b;` would be cheating?

Comment: Do you always have the condition in a string? Could you give more context on why does the `'$a < $b'` exist?

Comment: $a, $b,... (and many) are the decimal values read from mySQL table. The $condition is what the user selects in the interface (can have infinite permutations). Code has to return where all this condition is being satisfied in the mySQL table.

Comment: You're looking to `eval` code and that's rarely a good idea.

Comment: From your explanation there is no need to have the condition expressed as a string. If you have values for the variables declared you can compare them... Simple as that. Or am I missing something? As mentioned, refrain from using eval.

Comment: Using eval(), I have tried following code, which works:.......<?php
    $a = 21;
    $b = 2;
 
 if(eval("return $a==$b;"))
    {
         echo 'abc';
    }
?> .......... Understanding the security risk associated with use of eval(), can somebody suggest any other alternative

Comment: @McKean noted to refrain use of eval(). Brief explanation of Why the condition should be expressed as a string --> PHP code reads a table containing 4 decimals viz $a[], $b[], $c[], $d[], row by row and stores in array. There are 100s of Parameters which has a specifc formula eg: Parameter 1 = Average of ($a[1]+$b[0]+$c[1]+$d[0]) or any random formula. User may select condition 'Parameter 1 < Parameter 2' or 'Parameter 54/Parameter 23 = 2' or any random condition. This condition has to be checked row by row when the code reads the table. Pl suggest an alternative to eval().